# Calculate column by condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have table in df:

```
X1  X2
1   1
1   2
2   2
2   2
3   3
3   3
```

And i want calculate Y, where Y = Yprevious + 1 if X1=X1previous and X2=X2previous, elso 0. Y on first line = 0. Example.

```
X1  X2  Y
1   1   0
2   2   0
2   2   1
2   2   2
2   2   3
3   3   0
```

Not a duplicate... Previously, the question was simpler - addition with a value in a specific line. Now the term appears in the calculation process. I need some cumulative calculation

What I need, more example:

```
X1  X2  Y
1   1   0
2   2   0
2   2   1
2   2   2
2   2   3
3   3   0
3   3   1
2   2   0
```

What I get on the link to the duplicate

```
X1  X2  Y
1   1   0
2   2   0
2   2   1
2   2   2
2   2   3
3   3   0
3   3   1
2   2   4
```

Comment: I tried to explain how the difference. I tried your last answer (thanks for it), but this is a bit different.

Comment: Can you change sample data for explain why not dupe?

Comment: i add sample when i use df['Y'] = df.X2.shift().eq(df.X2)&df.X1.shift().eq(df.X1)*(df.Y+1).shift().fillna(0).astype(int)

Comment: Yes, but I think add example why dupe not working...

Comment: I missed. I'll try

Comment: I add example. The difference in the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with new columns by consecutive values:

```
df1 = df[['X1','X2']].ne(df[['X1','X2']].shift()).cumsum()

df['Y'] = df.groupby([df1['X1'], df1['X2']]).cumcount()
print (df)
   X1  X2  Y
0   1   1  0
1   2   2  0
2   2   2  1
3   2   2  2
4   2   2  3
5   3   3  0
6   3   3  1
7   2   2  0
```